# insert data + image from android to mysql via PHP not working

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, base64

i'm a beginner in android app development. i made an app which is inserting data to mysql via PHP script in a localhost.
when i was trying to send **text data only**, it works.
the problem is when i add the inserting image code, it doesn't work but the app didn't crash.
please see my code below. I tried to implement things from many tuts out there.

this code is for inserting data

```
buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        InputStream is = null;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,
                    options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);

            String address = "" + etAddress.getText().toString();
            String zipCode = "" + etZip.getText().toString();
            String identifier = "" + etIdentifier.getText().toString();
            String stories = "" + etStories.getText().toString();
            String year = "" + etYear.getText().toString();
            String name = "" + etName.getText().toString();
            String area = "" + etArea.getText().toString();
            String bName = "" + etbName.getText().toString();
            String usage = "" + etUsage.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipCode", zipCode));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identifier", identifier));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stories", stories));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", year));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area", area));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bName", bName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usage", usage));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename", fileName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedString));


            //setting up koneksi
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                //http post method (IP BISA BERUBAH KARENA LOCALHOST)
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.108/insert.php");

                //passing nameValuePairs ke http post
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                //getting response
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                //setting entity
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                //toast some message
                String msg = "Data Entered";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Log_tag", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

and this code for loading the image to an imageview

```
public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgPath));
            // Get the Image's file name
            String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
here's the PHP script

```
<br/>

<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("dbfema",$con);

$address=$_POST['address'];
$zipCode=$_POST['zipCode'];
$identifier=$_POST['identifier'];
$stories=$_POST['stories'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$area=$_POST['area'];
$bName=$_POST['bName'];
$usage=$_POST['usage'];
$base=$_REQUEST['image']
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `screening`(`alamat`, `kodePos`, `otherId`, `stories`, `yearBuilt`, `screenerName`, `totalArea`, `buildingName`, `usage`, `foto1`) values('$address','$zipCode','$identifier','$stories','$year','$name','$area','$bName','$usage','$filename')");

?>
```

is there something wrong with my methods?
i would be very grateful if the correction comes with the code.

Comment: Can you provide the `PHP` code too?

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me.
it's only an ";" after ['image'] is missing. it's already midnight in here.